# Empty Facebook share dialog box

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

There's a quite a few products and services on this site I manage. They all have a Facebook share dialog. However, when clicking on the share button (for all of them), an empty Facebook dialog box appears:

[image: The empty facebook share dialog]

My code is exactly what is given on the [facebook site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/):

```html
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Update: Found out that if I put the exact same link into my feed in facebook, it shows up as expected. So I guess this is something local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to +phwd over in the #facebook freenode chatroom for the answer:

My link was wrong. I should have included this in my original post. Here's what I had before:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?title&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.some_site.com%2Fsome_page
```

I needed to do 2 things to fix this:

1. Remove title
2. change url to u

So it comes out like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.some_site.com%2Fsome_page
```